# Adding layer to group in layers panel using PyQGIS, refreshing issue

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm developing a QGIS plugin, to load PostGIS layers in QGIS.

I'd like to :

- Create a layer group
- Add several layers in this group.

The code below adds the layer to the canvas, and in the layer panel. Only there is no interaction between the layer panel and the map.

However, if I close and reopen my project, the layer interacts correctly with the map.

I noticed that if I took the layer out of the group, then the map interacts correctly with the layer panel.

I think I'm missing an action to refresh the layer panel, or something like that. Does anyone have an idea?

```py
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(host, port, database, user, password)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), tablename, 'postgres')

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
mygroup = root.insertGroup(0, 'MyGroup')

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False) #Add Map layer
root.findGroup(mygroup ).addLayer(layer) #Add layer in group

iface.reloadConnections() #refresh
```

Comment: You can try `iface.mapCanvas().refresh()` and/or `QgsProject.instance().reloadAllLayers()`

Comment: You create layer "layer", but add to map "new_layer" - ...addMapLayer(new_layer, False) ...

Comment: I tried ```iface.mapCanvas().refresh()``` and ```QgsProject.instance().reloadAllLayers()```, but I have the same issue.  I corrected the code snippet, with the right layer variable "layer" (it was just a copy / paste error)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your problem is this line:

```py
root.findGroup(mygroup ).addLayer(layer) #Add layer in group
```

The [findGroup()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeGroup.html#a24079a54dc415727b6aa05b4f4260f26) method takes a string argument (the group name), but you are passing it a `QgsLayerTreeGroup` object (returned from the `insertGroup()` method and stored in your `mygroup` variable).

Since you already have a `QgsLayerTreeGroup` object, all you have to do is:

```py
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False)
mygroup.addLayer(layer)
```

So:

```py
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(host, port, database, user, password)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), tablename, 'postgres')

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
mygroup = root.insertGroup(0, 'MyGroup')

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False) #Add Map layer
mygroup.addLayer(layer) #Add layer in group
```

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't change anything :( All layers that are not in a group react well. 
But in groups, they don't respond properly until the project has been closed and reopened.